# Получить AssemblyVersion из Assembly

Tags: c#

Можно ли получить AssemblyVersion из Assembly без загрузки ее в процесс(Из файла)?

Answer (score 2):

Прочитайте `AssemblyName` вызовом [`System.Reflection.AssemblyName.GetAssemblyName(string assemblyFile);`](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.reflection.assemblyname.getassemblyname?view=netframework-4.8), у полученного объекта возьмите `Version`.

```
using System;
using System.Reflection;

public class AssemblyName_GetAssemblyName
{
   public static void Main()
   {
      AssemblyName myAssemblyName = AssemblyName.GetAssemblyName("MyAssembly.exe");
      Console.WriteLine(myAssemblyName.Version);
   }
}
```

Comment: Спасибо большое!